# What SQL query can be used to limit continious periods by parameter value, and then to calculate datediff inside them?

Tags: sql, datediff, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of phone calls consisting of user_id, call_date, city,
where city can be either A or B.
It looks like this:

| user_id | call_date | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-05 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-10 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-12 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-16 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-17 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-20 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-22 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-23 | A |
| 2 | 2021-01-24 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-26 | B |
| 2 | 2021-01-30 | A |

For this table, we need to select for each user all the periods when he was in city B.
These periods are counted in **days** and **start when the first call is made from city B, and end as soon as the next call is made from city A**.
So for user_id = 1 fist period starts on 2021-01-02 and ands on 2021-01-10. There can be several such periods for each user.

The result should be the following table:

| user_id | period_1 | period_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 | 6 |

Can you please tell me how I can limit the periods according to the condition of the problem, and then calculate the datediff within each period?
Thank you

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? If so please tag it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a typical [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) problem. You need to group consecutive rows first, then find the first `call_date` of the next group. Sample code for Postgres is below, the same may be adapted to another DBMS by applying appropriate function to calculate the difference in days.

> ```
> with a (user_id, call_date, city)
> as (
>   select *
>   from ( values
>     ('1', date '2021-01-01', 'A'),
>     ('1', date '2021-01-02', 'B'),
>     ('1', date '2021-01-03', 'B'),
>     ('1', date '2021-01-05', 'B'),
>     ('1', date '2021-01-10', 'A'),
>     ('1', date '2021-01-12', 'B'),
>     ('1', date '2021-01-16', 'A'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-17', 'A'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-20', 'B'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-22', 'B'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-23', 'A'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-24', 'B'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-26', 'B'),
>     ('2', date '2021-01-30', 'A')
>   ) as t
> )
> , grp as (
>   /*Identify groups*/
>   select a.*,
>     /*This is a grouping of consecutive rows:
>       they will have the same difference between
>       two row_numbers while the more detailed
>       row_number changes, which means the attribute had changed.
>
>     */
>     dense_rank() over(
>       partition by user_id
>       order by call_date asc
>     ) - 
>     dense_rank() over(
>       partition by user_id, city
>       order by call_date asc
>     ) as grp,
>     /*Get next call date*/
>     lead(call_date, 1, call_date)
>       over(
>         partition by user_id
>         order by call_date asc
>       ) as next_dt
>   from a
> )
> select
>   user_id,
>   city,
>   min(call_date) as dt_from,
>   max(next_dt) as dt_to,
>   max(next_dt) - min(call_date) as diff
> from grp
> where city = 'B'
> group by user_id, grp, city
> order by 1, 3
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | city | dt_from    | dt_to      | diff
> :------ | :--- | :--------- | :--------- | ---:
> 1       | B    | 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-10 |    8
> 1       | B    | 2021-01-12 | 2021-01-16 |    4
> 2       | B    | 2021-01-20 | 2021-01-23 |    3
> 2       | B    | 2021-01-24 | 2021-01-30 |    6
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=086e207be4c4d7e96b12c026a02dedaf)*

Comment: Thank you, astentx! That methodics works great!